# Separar entidad del contexto

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy trabajando con Entity Framework 4.5.2, Visual Studio 2015

Tengo la siguiente entidad.

```
public class Especificacion
    {
        public int EspecificacionId { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Opcion> Opciones { get; set; }
    }
```

Al momento de actualizar solo deseo actualizar la cabecera mas no la lista Opciones, se me ocurre que debo de separar del contexto Opciones.

```
public void Actualizar(Especificacion entity)
        {
            using (var context = new BusinessContext())
            {
                foreach (var d in entity.Opciones)
                {
                    context.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Detached;
                }

                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Pero en entity igual viene opciones, ¿como lo puedo solucionar?

> Error: {"Se han detectado cambios conflictivos al rol
>   'Opcion_Especificacion_Target' de la relación
>   'TecSoftware.Persistencia.Model.Opcion_Especificacion'."}

Por alguna razón hay problemas en el modelo
[image: captura]

Saludos!

Especificaciones

- EspecificacionId int
- Nombre varchar(80)

Opciones

- OpcionId int
- EspecificacionId int
- Nombre vaarchar(80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo enviandole una entidad simple, quiero decir sin la lista de opción

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEspecificacionId.Text))
            {
                var entity = new Especificacion()
                {
                    EspecificacionId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEspecificacionId.Text)
                        ? 0
                        : Convert.ToInt32(txtEspecificacionId.Text),
                    Nombre = txtNombre.Text,
                    Opciones = _list
                };
                _saEspecificacion.Registrar(entity);
                txtEspecificacionId.Text = Convert.ToString(entity.EspecificacionId);
            }
            else
            {
                var entity = new Especificacion()
                {
                    EspecificacionId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEspecificacionId.Text)
                        ? 0
                        : Convert.ToInt32(txtEspecificacionId.Text),
                    Nombre = txtNombre.Text
                };
                _saEspecificacion.Registrar(entity);
                txtEspecificacionId.Text = Convert.ToString(entity.EspecificacionId);
            }
```

Eso fue todo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deberías hacer es apuntar a la propiedad en particular a la que quieres modificar, me late que quieres cambiar el nombre solamente, si estoy entendiendo bien lo que estás buscando, el siguiente código te dará una mano:

```
public void Actualizar(Especificacion entity)
{
    using (var context = new BusinessContext())
    {        
        context.NombreDeTuTabla.Attach(entity);
        // La actualización es la siguiente línea:
        entity.Opciones = null;
        context.Entry(entity).Property(x=>x.Nombre).IsModified = true;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Más información: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

Comment: Exactamente es lo que necesito si ya había probado ese código, pero el problema que tengo es que, tengo un error que dice cambios conflictivos ¿sera porque en ambas entidades cabecera y detalle hay una propiedad con el mismo nombre la cual se llama "Nombre"?

Comment: Creo que ya sé lo que está pasando, necesitas poner null a esa lista de opciones en caso no la estés guardando, editando respuesta en 3...2.. :D

Comment: Es mejor que cambies la lista a una nueva. entity.Opciones = new List<Opcion>();

Comment: @fredyfx Así es, que puedo hacer si le mando una entidad simple sin la lista del detalle, puede ser voy a probar.

Comment: @fredyfx Actuliza la pregunta con el error que obtengo.

Comment: Actualiza la pregunta agregando la estructura de tu BD relacionada el tema.

Comment: @fredyfx Ya listo

Comment: Intenta agregar algún prefijo a la propiedad `Nombre`, por ejemplo `NombreEspecificacion` o `NombreOpcion` y veamos qué resulta :D

Comment: @fredyfx Sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Voy a poner en el hilo desde que escojo un registro e intento actualizarlo.

Comment: Se debe eliminar el objeto no relacionado le pasare una entidad simple(sin la lista Opciones)